# Global Timer in android

Tags: android, timer

I want to make a timer which will be shown on every activity of my application.

I know how to make a timer on an activity below is my code

```
public class Timer extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public TextView mTextField;
    private Button btnstart;

    public String formatTime(long millis) { 
        String output = "00:00"; 
        long seconds = millis / 1000; 
        long minutes = seconds / 60; 

        seconds = seconds % 60; 
        minutes = minutes % 60; 

        String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds); 
        String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes); 

        if (seconds < 10) 
            secondsD = "0" + seconds; 
        if (minutes < 10) 
            minutesD = "0" + minutes; 

        output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD; 
        return output; 
    } 
    public CountDownTimer Counter1;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        //Declare Start/Stop button 
        btnstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnThread1); 
        btnstart.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Button btnstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button02); 
        //Button btnpass = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button03);

        //Declare Text fields to show time left 
        final TextView mCounter1TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtThread1); 
        final TextView mCounter2TextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtThread2); 
        //final TextView mCounter3TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView03); 



        //Counter 1 
        Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(120000 , 1000) { 
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
                mCounter1TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished)); 
            } 

            public void onFinish() { 
                mCounter1TextField.setText("Finished!"); 
                // Counter1.start();
            } 
        }; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == btnstart)
        {
            Counter1.start();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to know how to make it global??

Comment: I think you want to have it in a service running in background. Have you read what android Timer can do? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: This is a clear use case for fragments. Have a single timer fragment always shown and you swap the others fragments in a single main activity. Don't make global an activity, remember that they can be recreated if some configuration change is fired, or a phone call comes in, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by making a timer in one activity and calling its protected function in my other activity.

This is the startTimer function to start the timer:

```
private void startTimer(){ 
    if (mTimer == null) { 
        mTimer = new Timer(); 
    } 
    if (mTimerTask == null) { 
        mTimerTask = new TimerTask() { 
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                Log.i(TAG, "count: "+String.valueOf(count)); 
                sendMessage(UPDATE_TEXTVIEW); 

                do { 
                    try { 
                        Log.i(TAG, "sleep(1000)..."); 
                        Thread.sleep(1000); 
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    }    
                } while (isPause);  
                count ++;   
            } 
        }; 
    } 
    if(mTimer != null && mTimerTask != null ) 
        mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, delay, period); 
}
```

and this is the public function which can be used by any other activity:

```
public String valueOfTimer()
{
    return String.valueOf(count);
}
```

and this is how I am getting the value on other activity:

```
private void updateTime()
{
    TimerActivity tm  = new TimerActivity();

    String time = tm.valueOfTimer();
    t2.setText(time);
    System.out.println("Time::"+time);
}
```

Comment: and what should i used if i want to cancel the timer from another activity?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a singleton class holding your `CountDownTimer`

```
// This is not a real singleton, Google to get a proper Java implementation
public class TimerSingleton {

  // Should not be public, you should of course encapsulate access to that timer.
  // static keyword says that one timer object is shared by all instance of TimerSingleton 
  public static CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();
}

// Access to the timer from an activity:
TimerSingleton.timer.start();
```

Second option is to have your timer as a member of a custom Application class: [Use Application class for global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984648/use-application-class-for-global-variables)

Third option : make a local service that starts the timer when started.

Keep in mind that in case of options 1 and 2, if the OS decides to kill you app, the timer will vanish (i.e. when the activity is re-created, the CountDownTimer object will be resetted).

Answer (score 1):

Create a Singleton! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

singleton guarantee that there will be only one object of some kind and makes it easy for any other object to access it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show it one every activity of your application, then I suggest you to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). All you need to do is to create a Fragment with your Timer class that will appear every time, another Fragment with other content you want to show, and manipulate the lifecycle of the second Fragment only.

Answer (score 1):

make  a singleton class and register listener in your ui.

```
 mTimerCustom = CountdownTimer.getInstance();
 mTimerCustom.registerListener(this);
 mTimerCustom.start();
```

in CountDownTimer class

```
 public static CountdownTimer getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

 public synchronized void start() {

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        int seconds=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
       start=60-seconds;
        //Toast.makeText(mParentActivity,""+seconds,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");
        switch (state) {
            case STOPPED:
                count = start;
            case PAUSED:
                timer = new Timer(TAG);
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (count > 0) {
                            count--;
                            Log.d(TAG, "Tick: " + count);
                            for (TimerListener listener : listeners) {
                                listener.timerUpdate(count);
                            }
                        }
                        else stop();
                    }
                }, 0, DELAY);
                state = COUNTING;
                if (D) Log.d(TAG, "state: counting");
                break;
            case COUNTING:
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException(state.toString());
        }
    }
```